# Sets package in R causing dplyr functions to error (Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables)

Tags: r, dplyr, set, tidyverse, janitor

It appears that when I have the sets package installed in my global environment, it affects dplyr and janitor functions from executing correctly. For example, I cannot perform a basic mutate function when it is installed, getting the error "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables". To reproduce, see the code below:

```
EXAMPLE OF SETS ERROR

remove.packages(c("dplyr", "sets"))
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria")
age <- c(23, 41, 32)

df <- data.frame(name, age)

data_2 <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(test = "test")

#looks good

## with sets
remove.packages(c("dplyr", "sets"))
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("sets")
library(dplyr)
library(sets)

name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria")
age <- c(23, 41, 32)

df <- data.frame(name, age)

data_2 <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(test = "test")
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `sets` package also has a [`pipe` operator](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sets/versions/1.0-18/topics/interval) (`%>%`) conflicting with `dplyr`'s pipe. One way to resolve this is to use [`conflicted` package](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/06/conflicted/). Note the sequence of loading package: `sets` package is loaded first and `conflict_prefer()` call is right after loading `dplyr`.

```
library(conflicted)
library(sets)
library(dplyr)
conflict_prefer("%>%", "dplyr")

name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria")
age <- c(23, 41, 32)
df <- data.frame(name, age)

data_2 <- df %>%
  mutate(test = "test")
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked like a charm after starting a new session + noting your comment on sequencing.